# MaterialBanner flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, widget

I have a Widget in flutter and I want to say when I clicked on button that has on MaterialBanner, MaterialBanner  should close and program continue their work.
What do I do?
if someone has a data please help me.
thanks.

MaterialBanner(
content: const Text('error please try later.'),
actions: [
TextButton(
onPressed: (){
SystemNavigator.pop();
},
child: const Text('خروج')
),
],
);

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to declare a bool value and then toggle that value on button click. Using that value, you can hide or show the Material banner. Use stateful widget and setState for this. For example.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    bool showBanner = false;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('The MaterialBanner is below'),
      ),
      body: showBanner? const MaterialBanner(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        content: Text('Hello, I am a Material Banner'),
        leading: Icon(Icons.agriculture_outlined),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFE0E0E0),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: null,
            child: Text('OPEN'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: (){
              setState(){
               showBanner = !showBanner;
              },
             },
            child: Text('DISMISS'),
          ),
        ],
      ):Container(),
    );
  }
}
```